# Android studio forcefully closed and now android studio is getting errors everywhere in every class in every project

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-studio

I was programming on android studio and my laptop ran into some error and crashed and so android studio was forcefully closed. When i restarted my laptop and re opened android studio im getting errors everywhere in places where they should not be for example where it says extends ActionBarActivity it comes up red. Basically almost everything is coming up red. Is this because android studio was forcefully closed? How do i fix this?

Example of errors
[image]

Above as you can see, these are the errors that appear in just one class. They are in every class like this. I backed up my project and reinstalled android studio but these errors are still coming up. Is there anyway to fix this?

Edit: On the words that are highlighted in red it says: Cannot resolve method

Comment: Try invalid cache and restart, from the file menu. Or try to run a Gradle sync

Comment: the invalid cache and restart worked thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try this

**file -> Invalidate Cashes / Restart**

that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Android Studio is pointing to the correct location of your Android SDK and Java SDK. I updated my Android Studio and it lost my SDK locations entirely. Right click on your project -> select module settings -> select Project tab -> make sure the location of your sdk is there.